# Facebook sharing Curl SSL connect error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ssl

For sharing content we use the facebook share dialog. This used to work fine until several weeks ago. We did not change anything on our side. I get two errors from the facebook debug tool. One about an og property not set (but it is) and a curl SSL error.

An example of a link we share is:
https://www.globalpetalert.com/web/en/pets/missing/8906/

All necessary open graph parameters have been set.

The errors from the debug tool:

Object at URL 'https://www.globalpetalert.com/web/en/pets/missing/8906/' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

Curl Error : SSL_CONNECT_ERROR error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

- The og:title is provided.
- The SSL_CONNECT_ERROR I do not understand.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: According to several SSL check tools on the net, your site only supports older versions of encryption – https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ f.e. reports that your site only supports TLS 1.0, but not 1.1 or 1.2. It looks like Facebook is expecting you to be a little more “up-to-date” security-wise – so see to it that you get that upgraded to a proper, contemporary level.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I'll look into that, Inno